# Reference for a statement about upper triangular unipotent matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, lie-groups

I am revising a paper, and a referee of that paper asked if the following little lemma we proved there is known:

``Let $X$ be an $n\times n$ upper triangular unipotent matrix over $\mathbb R$.  There exists an $n\times n$ upper triangular unipotent matrix $Y$ with integer entries such that for $1 \leq i < j \leq n$ the absolute values of the $(i,j)$ entries of both $XY$ and $(XY)^{-1}$ are less than or equal to the coefficient of $x^{j-i}$ in the Maclaurin series of $\exp(\frac{x}{2(1-x)})$."

The referee suggested us to ask some Lie theorists, particularly those who work with discrete subgroups.  I have asked several experts and they all said that they are not aware of such results.  So the next logical step is to ask a broader community.  If any of you happen to know a reference of this lemma or a more general statement, I would appreciate a reference.

Thanks.

Comment: It's helpful to have a more specific title than "reference requested".  I made an edit but feel free to change it to something else if you want.